# How to embed a table in php code?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create a table and give values to its rows but it is not working. Any hint or advice will be appreciated:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<style>
table,th,td
{
border:1px solid black;
border-collapse:collapse;
}
th,td
{
padding:5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<?php
    $subject = "ISIT307";
    $location = "3.123";
    $time = "4:30";

<table style="width:300px">
<tr>
  <th>Subject</th>
  <th>location</th> 
  <th>time</th> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>$subject</td>
  <td>$location</td> 
  <td>$time</td>
</tr>
</table>
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $subject; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $location; ?></td> 
  <td><?php echo $time; ?></td>
</tr>
```

You need to use `<?php` and `?>` whenever you would like to run php code.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error after $time = "4:30"; You can't output html directly through php else you call echo or print.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<style>
table,th,td
{
border:1px solid black;
border-collapse:collapse;
}
th,td
{
padding:5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<?php
    $subject = "ISIT307";
    $location = "3.123";
    $time = "4:30";
?>

<table style="width:300px">
<tr>
  <th>Subject</th>
  <th>location</th> 
  <th>time</th> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><?= $subject ?></td>
  <td><?= $location ?></td> 
  <td><?= $time ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just copy paste this but the table is empty!

Answer (score 0):

You can't have html in your php, and you can't have php in your html.

```
<?php
    $subject = "ISIT307";
    $location = "3.123";
    $time = "4:30";
?>

<table style="width:300px">
<tr>
  <th>Subject</th>
  <th>location</th> 
  <th>time</th> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><?=$subject ?></td>
  <td><?=$location ?></td> 
  <td><?=$time ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I tried this but it is not showing data in the table :(

Comment: Then try combining my answer with Chris'. You probably don't have short_open_tag activated (for some reason). Just use the simple echo.